# Unreachable website

Tags: php, .htaccess, plupload, cloudflare

I have problems with my website being ureachable every few minutes. It usually happens when I try to upload some photos and site just becomes unreachable. But if I try with proxy it works fine at the same time. If I look in errorlog it just fills it with errors "File not found...".

I have been using CloudFlare with development mode on. When the site is unreachable it gives CloudFlare error like this: http://shrani.si/f/1A/Ly/pcIY0EL/cf1.jpg
I also use htaccess for friendly urls.

.htaccess:

```
#---------WWW FIX-------#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#---GZIP COMPRESSION----#
#########################
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

#-----FILES EXPIRE------#
#########################
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
<filesMatch ".(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
<filesMatch ".(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

#########################
#-----FRIENDLY URL------#
Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 

#user
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/user/([0-9]+)([/])?$ user.php?user=$2&language=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/user/([0-9]+)/public([/])?$ user.php?        user=$2&view=public&language=$1

#tractor-list
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/tractors([/])?$ tractor-list.php?language=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/tractors/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9\-]+)([/])?$ tractor-list.php?    manufacturer=$2&language=$1

#tractor-model
#just tractor
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/tractor/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9\-\.]+)([/])?$ tractor.php?    tractor=$2&language=$1
#tractor and component
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/tractor/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9\-\.]+)/([a-z]+)([/])?$     tractor.php?tractor=$2&language=$1&component_type=$4
#tractor,component,component id
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/tractor/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-z0-9\-\.]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)([/])?$ tractor.php?tractor=$2&language=$1&component_type=$4&component_id=$5

#home
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/home([/])?$ index.php?language=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})([/])?$ /$1/home [R=301,L]

#compare
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/compare/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)([/])?$ tractor-compare.php?    language=$1&tractor1=$2&tractor2=$3
```

part of erreorlog:

```
[Tue May 21 03:16:43 2013] [error] [client 193.189.190.66] File does not exist:        /home/162175/domains/sitename.com/html/sl, referer: http://www.sitename.com/sl/tractor/106/New-Holland-T4050-Deluxe
[Tue May 21 03:16:44 2013] [error] [client 193.189.190.66] File does not exist:     /home/162175/domains/sitename.com/html/sl, referer: http://www.sitename.com/sl/tractor/106/New-Holland-T4050-Deluxe
[Tue May 21 03:16:44 2013] [error] [client 193.189.190.66] File does not exist: /home/162175/domains/sitename.com/html/sl, referer: http://www.sitename.com/sl/tractor/106/New-Holland-T4050-Deluxe
```

I have also checked and page does not contain any dead urls (Google chrome extension Check My Links).

What is the problem?